# MVC 5 razor view show images in actual size without distortion or stretching

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to display some images in a table in actual sizes. I resized the original into 3 large medium and thumbnail. I am trying to use styles, but currently it is distorting the images, making them very blurry.

How do manipulate the style or whatever to correctly size these without distortion. I know the sizes in px. 
Large is 1900 x 1406
Medium is 400 x 296
Small is 100 x 100

I provide two samples below First I want to display the medium one but shrink it a little.
second I want to show all three in actual size.

```
<div class="row">
    @{
        foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder))
        {
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(item.OrderedImages[0].LargeImage))" onclick="javascript:window.open('@item.OrderedImages[0].FilePathLarge');" alt="@item.OrderedImages[0].Name" />
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)</h2>
                        <p>
                            @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("datepicker" + @item.ID))
                            @if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("admin"))
                            {
                                <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Products", new { id = @item.ID })" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Edit Item</a>

                            }
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Products")" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Add to Cart</a>
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Products")" class="btn btn-default">More Info</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>



@model IEnumerable<MVC.CFC.Domain.Models.ProductImage>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DisplayOrder)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LargeImage)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MediumImage)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ThumbImage)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DisplayOrder)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="overflow:hidden;width:1900px;height:auto">
                    <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(item.LargeImage))" alt="@item.Name" style="width: 50%; height: auto;" />
                </div>
            <td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <img class="img-rounded" src="data:image/jpg;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(item.MediumImage))" alt="@item.Name" />
                </div>
            <td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <img class="img-rounded" src="data:image/jpg;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(item.ThumbImage))" alt="@item.Name" />
                </div>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly add the size in the html of your image tag.

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(item.OrderedImages[0].LargeImage))"
onclick="javascript:window.open('@item.OrderedImages[0].FilePathLarge');"
alt="@item.OrderedImages[0].Name" height="@item.OrderedImages[0].height"
width="@item.OrderedImages[0].width"/>
```

Comment: I added it as you suggested and It does two things 1 it does make it larger but not the full 1900 size and second it makes the image very blurry. My guess is that the containers are messing with the size somehow.

Comment: **face palm**  I found the issue.  I was loading the thumb image in the model.. oops!! thanks for the help